# Como conseguir datos de un array JSon en un mismo archivo

Tags: javascript, array, json

En pocas palabras yo agarro los valores de unos inputs, lo convierto en una cadena y los separo por , con split, y luego, eso lo agrego a un array, decidí hacerlo en formato JSon porque me gusta como se ve ordenado, pero cuando intente llamar al array, en un valor en especifico me retorno undefined, el html creo que se puede obviar, son solo inputs de texto y dos select.
js.js

```
let fullData = Name.value + "," + Acronym.value + "," + Day.options[Day.selectedIndex].text + "," + Hours.options[Hours.selectedIndex].text + "," + pDay.options[pDay.selectedIndex].text + "," + Practice.options[Practice.selectedIndex].text;
let splitData = fullData.split(",");

arrayClass.push([{'Nombre' : splitData[0], //se agregan los valores al JSon.
        'Siglas' : splitData[1],
        'Día de teoría' : splitData[2],
        'Hora de teoría' : splitData[3],
        'Día de práctica' : splitData[4],
        'Hora de práctica' : splitData[5]}]);
```

Así es como asigno los valores, y cuando los quería llamar (el mismo archivo, pero otra función, y el array lo declare afuera de cualquier función), use la siguiente forma, la variable rdbX es el index, según un radiobutton que selecciono, pues toma ese id, y agarro el id del radiobutton, que ya lo controlo y se que no me da otro valor.

```
Name.value = arrayClass[rdbX].Nombre;
```

Y pues ahí me tira "undefined", no se si estoy llamando mal al valor, alguien me ayuda, y si el titulo de la pregunta esta mal, corregirme, no se exactamente como llamarle a este array, y no se si existe un termino para referenciar valores en un mismo archivo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es que has creado un array bidimensional, no se si es lo que queírs, pero me por la forma de acceder creo que no.

```
arrayClass.push([ {'Nombre' : splitData[0], //se agregan los valores al JSon.
        'Siglas' : splitData[1],
        'Día de teoría' : splitData[2],
        'Hora de teoría' : splitData[3],
        'Día de práctica' : splitData[4],
        'Hora de práctica' : splitData[5]}  ])
```

Fíjate que has metido en arrayClass un array con el objeto {'Nombre'....}. Entonces cada elemento de arrayClass es otro array.
Si quitas los corchetes

```
arrayClass.push( {'Nombre' : splitData[0], //se agregan los valores al JSon.
        'Siglas' : splitData[1],
        'Día de teoría' : splitData[2],
        'Hora de teoría' : splitData[3],
        'Día de práctica' : splitData[4],
        'Hora de práctica' : splitData[5]} )
```

Ahora en arrayClass[0].Nombre tendrás el valor que corresponda.

Comment: O es cierto jajajajajaja, muchas gracias ya me funciono.